# Re-arrange items in checklist in Notes 4 app in El Capitan

Tags: macos, notes.app

[image]

The Notes 4 app bundled with El Capitan is revamped. It now includes a checklist feature. This feature becomes available after you agree to "upgrade" (convert) your existing data.

**Is there some way to re-order the items in a checklist?**

I tried dragging, but I cannot find any thing on which to click to initiate the drag. I looked at the context menu, but no such item. The main menus offer a `Format` > `Mark as Checked` item, but nothing about moving items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with macOS Catalina, you can position the cursor on an item, and then use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to move the item up or down, respectively.

- <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>
- <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

See also pages from Apple’s *Notes User Guide*:

- [Write and format notes on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/notes/write-and-format-notes-not9474646a9/4.8/mac/11.0) (Big Sur 11)
- [Write and format notes on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/notes/write-and-format-notes-not9474646a9/4.7/mac/10.15) (Catalina 10.15)

> Move a list item up (or down) in the list: Press Control-Command-Up Arrow (or Control-Command-Down Arrow).

Furthermore, checked items can auto-sort to the bottom. Enable this feature by checking *Automatically sort checked items* in *Preferences*.

Answer (score 3):

#### Drag and drop worked for me (OS Version: 10.11.1 (15B42)):

1. Here is the list

[image]

2. Select the line item that you want to move

[image]

3.Drag it to the new place (using `cmd` `click`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no real functionality for re-ordering checklist items; these **cannot be rearranged** properly through dragging or any other shortcut in the latest version of Notes (*Notes 4.0 on El Capitan*).

At present, the checklists should be treated like interactive bullet points. They can only be selected and moved around in the same way that text can; I have experimented with the feature thoroughly.

Re-orderable lists can be suggested to Apple via their standard [Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback) form.

Answer (score 0):

Triple click on a line, then move the cursor the the beginning of the line where you want to put it(it will move the selected item before that line). You cannot move a line to the one that's bellow, because it is already before that line.